# FB.init keeps adding fbsr_* cookies

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cookies

I'd like to use Facebook Login/Connect to authenticate users on my website.  The system consists of two things: 1) client side use of the FB JS SDK to auth the user and to set a (fbsr_) cookie, 2) retrieve this cookie on the server side and make a request against FB backend to get their email, that I'll use as an ID.  (I'll use G+ login etc as well so email looks like a good common denominator.)

I pretty much copied what's here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

The problem is, every time I refresh the page, I see that a new fbsr_${my_app_id} cookie is created.  After 10 reloads in a row, I end up with 10 cookies that have the same name (and same domain) and different content.  In other words, it looks like FB.init() always creates a new cookie and doesn't re-use the previous one (which becomes invalid).  My observation is based on what I see in the "Cookies" window of Firefox in this case.

Am I doing something wrong?  What can I do so the FB API reuses the previous cookie and doesn't create a myriad of cookies with the same name on my domain?

Thanks!